# Transform the CSV to XML in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I have a scenario where the data is extracted from oracle in the form of CSV and then it should be transformed to desired XML format.

### Input CSV File:

```
Id,SubID,Rank,Size
1,123,1,0.1
1,234,2,0.2
2,456,1,0.1
2,123,2,0.2
```

### Expected XML output:

```
<AA_ITEMS>
<Id ID="1">
    <SubId ID="123">
        <Rank>1</Rank>
        <Size>0.1</Size>
    </SubId>
    <SubId ID="234">
        <Rank>2</Rank>
        <Size>0.2</Size>
    </SubId>
</Id>
<Id ID="2">
    <SubId ID="456">
        <Rank>1</Rank>
        <Size>0.1</Size>
    </SubId>
    <SubId ID="123">
        <Rank>2</Rank>
        <Size>0.2</Size>
    </SubId>
</Id>
```

Note: The CSV file is a daily load and contains around 150K to 200K records
Please assist. Thanks in advance

Comment: Assist with what? Please explain what the problem is. Why is the question tagged "python-2.7"? That is an obsolete version of Python.

Comment: Untagged the obsolete version, my bad it got included.

Comment: OK. But what is the problem? Have you done any research? You are not the first to ask about "CSV to XML in Python":  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=csv+to+xml+python+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to approach it and though some people dislike building xml from a template, I believe it works best:

```
from itertools import groupby
from lxml import etree
csv_string = """[your csv ab0ve]
"""

#first deal with the csv
#split it into lines and discard the headers
lines = csv_string.splitlines()[1:]
#group the lines by the first character
grpfunc = lambda x: x[0]
grps = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(lines, grpfunc)]

#now convert the whole thing into xml:
xml_string = """
<AA_ITEMS>
"""
for grp in grps:
    elem = f'  <Id ID="{grp[0][0]}">'
    for g in grp:
        entry = g.split(',')
        #create an entry template:
        id_tmpl = f"""      
        <SubId ID="{entry[1]}">
            <Rank>{entry[2]}</Rank>
            <Size>{entry[3]}</Size>
        </SubId>
"""
        elem+=id_tmpl
    #close elem
    elem+="""</Id>
    """
    xml_string+=elem
#close the xml string
xml_string += """</AA_ITEMS>"""

#finally, show that the output is well formed xml:
print(etree.tostring(etree.fromstring(xml_string)).decode())
```

The output should be your expected xml.